# Youtube YTHelper view video playback starting automatically after pause

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, youtube, youtube-api

Using [YTHelper](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper) view to play youtube video, issues we are facing are

1. if we pause video it still starts playing again automatically
2. when video is playing in full screen, if user clicks on done button, it stops playing and after few seconds it starts playing automatically in full screen.

   ```
   NSDictionary *playerVars = @{

                            @"playsinline" : @0,
                            @"autoplay" : @0,
                            @"showinfo" : @0,
                            @"autohide" : @0,
                            @"rel" : @0,
                            @"modestbranding" : @1
                            };

   self.playerView.delegate = self;
   [self.playerView loadWithVideoId:@"M7lc1UVf-VE" playerVars:playerVars];
   ```

[Sample code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xq8ol8x5chify1f/Youtube.zip?dl=0) attached for reference.

Comment: I have same problem, and not working all delegate methods! Are you find answer?

Comment: @rusBogun not found any solution yet, reported issue on their github page, https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper/issues/86

Answer (score 3):

You have to remove `window.setInterval(forcePlay, 5000);` from the `YTPlayerView-iframe-player.html` file and it should fix the problem.